# Query to only grab entities with multiple sessions in a single date?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am trying to write a query to grab Employees that have multiple shifts in one date but with a start and end date query.

For example, I am passing in these two variables: startDate = 1/14 and endDate = 1/20.

If Employee Paul has two shifts on 1/18, I want to grab him. If Terry has one shift on 1/17, do not grab him. If Paul has two shifts on 1/19 as well, he should show up on 4 lines, one for each shift.

This is a basis of the query I've formed so far

```
SELECT e.EmployeeID
   ,s.ShiftID
   ,s.ShiftDate
   ,s.ShiftType
FROM Employee e
JOIN Shift s ON s.EmployeeId = e.EmployeeId AND (s.Date >= @startDate AND s.Date <= @endDate)
--This is the part I'm struggling with and is wrong somehow
WHERE (
        SELECT COUNT(s2.ShiftId)
        FROM Shift s2
        WHERE s2.EmployeeId = e.EmployeeId AND s2.Date = s.Date AND s2.ShiftType IN ('TypeA', 'TypeB')
) > 1)
    AND s.ShiftType IN ('TypeA', 'TypeB')
```

Can someone help me? My WHERE filter is wrong somehow, but the basics of it is that I'm only trying to grab entries with multiple shifts on the same days within two date parameters. How would I formulate this query and am I on the right track? I hoped that this would work but I see an entry in my results where someone only has one entry in 1/14 and still appeared in my list.

Comment: Consumable DDL, sample data and expected results would help reduce the guessing we need to do to help you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't see why any aggregation is needed.  You just need to look for another shift on the same day for the same employee:

```
SELECT s.*
FROM Shift s 
WHERE s.Date >= @startDate AND
      s.Date <= @endDate AND
      s.ShiftType IN ('TypeA', 'TypeB') AND
      EXISTS (SELECT 1
              FROM Shift s2
              WHERE s2.EmployeeId = s.EmployeeId AND
                    s2.Date = s.Date AND
                    s2.ShiftType IN ('TypeA', 'TypeB') AND
                    s2.ShiftId <> s.ShiftId
             );
```

Note that this does not include the `employee` table in either the outer query or the subquery.  You may need it in the outer query.  I see no purpose in the subquery.

Comment: Is your code snippet of the subquery specifically? It looks like this may work if I throw it in the WHERE clause?

Comment: @Soulzityr . . . This should return what you want.  It is the entire query.

Comment: Hey @Gordon Linoff, thanks but actually in the outer query I need the Employee table too as my outer query actually pulls in other information like Display Names, location data, etc. I tried adding an EXISTS condition but it made me return a result of 0 even though at least one should show up (I created a test employee)

Comment: @Soulzityr . . . Do they have the same `shiftid`?  I am assuming that is unique in the `shift` table.

Comment: Nope, I had a typo in my implementation. This solution worked for me. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can use "WHERE EXISTS" for a query like this:

```
SELECT e.EmployeeID
   ,s.ShiftID
   ,s.ShiftDate
   ,s.ShiftType
FROM Employee e
JOIN Shift s ON s.EmployeeId = e.EmployeeId 
    AND (s.Date >= @startDate AND s.Date <= @endDate)
WHERE EXISTS (
    SELECT 1
    FROM Shift s2
    WHERE s2.EmployeeId = s.EmployeeId 
        AND s2.Date = s.Date
    GROUP BY s2.EmployeeId, s2.Date
    HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
)
```

You can also run this query to see just the Shift records (what the EXISTS query above is based on):

```
SELECT 
    s.EmployeeId, s.Date, COUNT(*)
FROM Shift s
GROUP BY s.EmployeeId, s.Date
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
```

Comment: Not sure what I did wrong, I moved the query over but it returned a result of 0 but when I check my data I can see that at least one person should be returning.

Comment: Does the shift date field have a time on it?